# CMake: Convert relative path to absolute path, with build directory as current directory

Tags: cmake

In CMake, you can convert relative paths to absolute paths using

```
get_filename_component(ABSOLUTE_PATH ${RELATIVE_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
```

However, paths such as `../../other_program/` are based on the **source directory** (i.e. the directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` files is), not the **build directory** (i.e. the directory from which `cmake` is called). This can lead to some confusion if you give a relative path as a command line option.

Is there a way to tell `get_filename_component` that it should base the relative path on the current binary dir instead of the current source dir?

Comment: A few years later `get_filename_comnponent` has been superseeded by `file(REALPATH "some/path" MY_PATH_VAR BASE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")` see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#real-path

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the docs of [`get_filename_component`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/get_filename_component.html) *(highlighting be me)*
:

> ```
> get_filename_component(<VAR> <FileName>
>                        <COMP> [BASE_DIR <BASE_DIR>]
>                        [CACHE])
> ```
>
> Set `<VAR>` to the absolute path of `<FileName>`, where `<COMP>` is one of:
>
> `ABSOLUTE` = Full path to file
>   `REALPATH` = Full path to existing file with symlinks resolved
>
> **If the provided `<FileName>` is a relative path, it is evaluated relative to the given base directory `<BASE_DIR>`.** If no base directory is provided, the default base directory will be `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.
>
> Paths are returned with forward slashes and have no trailing slashes. If the optional `CACHE` argument is specified, the result variable is added to the cache.

Thus, you use:

```
get_filename_component(buildDirRelFilePath "${myFile}"
                       REALPATH BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

---

To convert an absolute path to a file into a relative paths, you might use the [`file` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/file.html):

> ```
> file(RELATIVE_PATH <variable> <directory> <file>)
> ```
>
> Compute the relative path from a `<directory>` to a `<file>` and store it in the `<variable>`.

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH buildDirRelFilePath "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "${myFile}")
```

Comment: Yes, this solution is ideal for CMake versions 3.4 and higher. For older CMake versions (down to version 2.6) mike.did's solution is the best way to handle it.

Comment: Please always use `CMAKE_CURRENT_[BINARY|SOURCE]_DIR` instead of just the `CMAKE_[BINARY|SOURCE]_DIR` variables. The latter mess a lot of things up for people trying to use your library in a bigger project.

Comment: This works well for the in-source build. However, for the out of source build (`cmake -S src -B build`) the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` shows the `build` directory, not the top source directory. What should be used for out of source build? Or better yet - work for both.

Comment: @ilya1725 The answer was already in Qix's comment just above yours: use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to get `src` (instead of `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to get `build`).

Comment: Or use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` as base, which expands to **directory of the CMake file** (the file you write that inside).

Answer (score 27):

```
get_filename_component(MY_RESULT_ABSOLUTE_PATH_VAR
                       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${MY_RELATIVE_PATH_VAR}"
                       ABSOLUTE)
```

Comment: This syntax does not exist

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_filename_component.html  
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html

ABSOLUTE_PATH - target variable;
RELATIVE_PATH - source variable with part of the path

Comment: My bad. Please edit the question to make the variables clear so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: This won't work if `MY_RELATIVE_PATH_VAR` could contain an absolute path.

Answer (score 4):

You could check whether path is absolute with `if(IS_ABSOLUTE path)` and if it isn't prepend the base directory you want. For example,

```
if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE ${p})
    set(p "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${p}")
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

CMake 3.20 comes with a new way to do this, using the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html#absolute-path) command:

```
cmake_path(ABSOLUTE_PATH <path-var> [BASE_DIRECTORY <input>] [NORMALIZE]
                                    [OUTPUT_VARIABLE <out-var>])
```

`BASE_DIRECTORY` defaults to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, but can be overriden.